# Background Image with Full Height but responsive Width using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image with height 1400 and width 1000 , if i use any full screen background jquery plugin or code it crops from top or bottom and make it fit the whole screen but what i want is a plugin or code which will make sure the background image is responsive based on width of browser yet the full height of background image should be visible with scroll bar. currently it crops height from top and bottom.

if thats not possible atleast the crop should be only from bottom to maintain aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.background{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url(path/to/image.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will only crop the bottom off, but make sure the image 'covers' the entire element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rkf6Q/

To show 100% height, and have the width cropped, just set the `background-size` parameter to `auto 100%`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rkf6Q/1/

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to make sure the full height is visible? with css or javascript?